# Carsouel nothing working and js code has no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, strict

I am trying to get this carousel working using jQuery strict mode, when clicking on the prev and next button nothing is responding and weird part is there is no errors in the console. Am i missing something from the code.

html:

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Micah FED Conclusive Exercise</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inc/css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inc/css/base.css" />
    <script src="inc/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="inc/js/base.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
                <li>Four</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h2 class="logo">LOGO</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="page-content">
        <section class="main-carousel">
            <div class="carousel-next">&gt;</div>
            <div class="carousel-prev">&lt;</div>
            <div class="carousel-cells">
                <article>
                    <div class="slide-text">
                        <h1>Slide One</h1>
                        <p>A slide about sliding slides.</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <div class="slide-text">
                        <h1>Slide Two</h1>
                        <p>A slide-sliding slider sliding slides.</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <div class="slide-text">
                        <h1>Slide Three</h1>
                        <p>A slide-sliding slider sliding slides.</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="column-content">
            <h1>Three Columns</h1>
            <div class="three-columns">
                <aside class="list-block">
                    <h3>List Heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
                <aside class="list-block">
                    <h3>List Heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
                <aside class="list-block">
                    <h3>List Heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
                <aside class="list-block">
                    <h3>List Heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the jQuery bit instead i have to do this using strict mode. Which i find difficult

jQuery:

```
(function() {

var Carousel = {
    props:{
        current_slide:1,
        total_slides:3
    },
    init:function(){
        Carousel.next();
        Carousel.previous();
    },
    bindEvents:function(){
        $(".carousel-next").on("click",function(){
            alert('next');
            Carousel.next();
        });
        $(".carousel-prev").on("click",function(){
            Carousel.previous();
        });
    },
    next:function(){
        this.props.current_slide += 1;
    },
    previous:function(){
        this.props.current_slide -= 1;
    },
    update:function(){

    }
}
$(function(){
    Carousel.init();
})
```

})(window);

Comment: Why? Strict mode is not necessary... And ypur update function looks quite empty...

Comment: What is the error you are getting in strict mode?

Comment: It is for a test that i am doing for applying a job

Comment: @Hoyen i am getting no error and the slider is not working

Comment: Please check debugger console for errors and tell us what exactly is not working.

Comment: @MicahKwaka then your title is misleading and has nothing to do with strict mode. You don't have any code in here that will make the Carousel work. Is the carousel initialized somewhere else with a plugin such as slick?

Comment: @Hoyen i edit the question hopefully makes more sense

Comment: @Stefan basically with the code above I have. Unfortunately the slider is not working when I click on next and previous buttons so I think I must be missing something.

Comment: Have you tried to see if there are errors in the debug console? Normally you can access this console by pressing F12 in your browser.